# Do stomach flu has some benefits?

Tags: gastroenterology, stomach, benefits, influenza

I recently had stomach flu. I think I feel even better than before having the stomach flu. Could gastroenteritis be beneficial for the organism and serve as a reset and a path to default wellness?

Comment: Yeah it entitles you to a day off work.

Comment: @NinjaDoc Or the opportunity to be a hero by showing up at work despite being ill and spreading your norovirus to everyone else.